# 'setState' of useState hook occurs twice by one call

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

There is a board with squares their value relies on an array, it is handled with `useState` hook. Every click should raise the value by one, but unfortunately, it raises it by two (except the first click).

My questions are:

(1) Why is it happen, (2) how to avoid it, and, in general, (3) is there a better way to handle such an array with hooks.

```
let emptyBoard = Array.from({ length: parseInt(props.rows, 10) }, () =>
    new Array(parseInt(props.columns, 10)).fill(0)
  );

  const [squaresValues, setSquaresValue] = useState(emptyBoard);

  function onClick(id) {
    const [rowIndex, cellIndex] = id;
    console.log("the " + id + " square was clicked");
    setSquaresValue(prevValues => {      
      let newBoard = [...prevValues];
      console.log("before: " + newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex]);
      newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex] = newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex] + 1;
      console.log("after: " + newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex]);
      return newBoard;
    }
    );
  }
```

The log:

```
the 3,0 square was clicked 
before: 0 
after: 1 
the 3,0 square was clicked 
before: 1 
after: 2 
before: 2 
after: 3
```

As can be seen, from the second click the value is raised twice by every click.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856

The setState being called twice in development is a forced feature by react, to make sure your setState is independent and idempotent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were still mutating state, if you have pure components then they won't re render when mutating. Doing the full state copy with JSON.parse is a bad idea if you have pure components because everything will be re rendered.

```
let newBoard = [...prevValues];
newBoard[rowIndex] = [...newBoard[rowIndex]];
newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex] =
newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex] + 1;
```

Comment: Your solution works, thank you, but I don't understand why... 

can you explain please?

Comment: I agree, this is better solution

Comment: @yoni You were mutating state and that can break re rendering. More info on how to not mutate state can be found [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Udaya Prakash in the comment above, it's being called twice to make sure your setState is independent and idempotent. So, if I understand correctly, it being called twice is not a bug, but your values being changed the second time is.

Here's Dan Abramov's comment from the same GitHub issue:

> It is expected that setState updaters will run twice in strict mode in development. This helps ensure the code doesn't rely on them running a single time (which wouldn't be the case if an async render was aborted and alter restarted). If your setState updaters are pure functions (as they should be) then this shouldn't affect the logic of your application.

We can fix it by deep-copying your `prevValues` instead of shallow-copying with spread operator. As you might already know, there are multiple ways to deep copy your object, we could go with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)` for now, which you can replace with [your favorite kind from here](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities)

```
setSquaresValue(prevValues => {
  let newBoard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevValues)); // <<< this
  console.log("before: " + newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex]);
  newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex] = newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex] + 1;
  console.log("after: " + newBoard[rowIndex][cellIndex]);
  return newBoard;
});
```

I've kind of simulated it in [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-stallman-3umv2) if you want to play around.

Comment: Just clarifying, shallow copy doesn't work here because it's a two-dimensional array, and only 1 dimension can be shallow copied. Am I right or am I confusing something else?

Btw, great answer and explanation

Comment: @UdayaPrakash I think you are right. Anything on the second level or further will keep the reference (when shallow-copied) and hence the issue appears.

Comment: tanmay, @UdayaPrakash, so What do you suggest to bypass this problem?

Comment: @yoni If you are already using lodash, you could use `cloneDeep` for deep cloning, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` is also fine if you have a smallish object I reckon, or you could go with the approach in other answer by HMR